# Javascript switch statement undefined error

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I am exceuting this AJAX request in a google chrome extension; which logs an error in the chrome console:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid value for argument 1. Expected 'object' but got 'string'. - extensions/extension_process_bindings.js:66

chromeHidden.validate - extensions/extension_process_bindings.js:66

(anonymous function) - extensions/extension_process_bindings.js:622

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange - popup.html:362
```

Although only one of those errors is in my code, I think it's this section (The line that flags up is marked)

```
var xmlhttp;
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    if (xmlhttp.responseText != 0)
      {
      chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText(xmlhttp.responseText); // LINE 362 - FINAL ERROR
      chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor(255,0,0,255);
      document.getElementById("alerts").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://adams-site.x10.mx/checkalerts.php?

day="+dayname,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to a [sample from the Chrome extension site](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/browserAction/make_page_red/background.js?revision=107094&view=markup) ([and the API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html#method-setBadgeText)) you need to pass an object (which the error suggests) instead of just passing the text.

From the sample:

```
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:String(i)});
```

So likely you just need:

```
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: xmlhttp.responseText });
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrong way to call the setBadgeText function ( http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html)

```
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: xmlhttp.responseText});
```

should work. Same is true for the setBadgeBackgroundColor too btw.

Comment: Thanks, though it worked fine with the background colour as it was. (Maybe I'm just using the default)

Answer (score 2):

The `chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText` takes an `Object` and not a `String` (as indicated by your error message). Here's a link to the [documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html#method-setBadgeText). Try changing your code to:

```
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
    text: xmlhttp.responseText
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I had actually seen that page, but it just confused me, ojects..strings..integers...